# Locating second, third, fourth,...eigth element in protractor using css locator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I have been testing using protractor and no way to refer the element except via css because it only do have class attribute given. The problem is there are more than 7 elements having this class name. Thus I use the syntax

```
element.all(by.css('h4.ng-binding')).first();
```

for the first one and it works fine but for the others it doesn't work! I use the same logic that I used also for the first one. Here is my snippets code for the others to locate them.

```
  element.all(by.css('h4.ng-binding')).second();
  element.all(by.css('h4.ng-binding')).third();
  element.all(by.css('h4.ng-binding')).fourth();
  element.all(by.css('h4.ng-binding')).fifth();
  element.all(by.css('h4.ng-binding')).sixth();
  element.all(by.css('h4.ng-binding')).seventh();
  element.all(by.css('h4.ng-binding')).eighth();
```

Answer (score 22):

There are no functions of those kind in protractor. Only available functions are [`first()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.first), [`last()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.last) and [`get()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get). You can implement everything using these 3 functions on top of the `ElementArrayFinder`. Here's how -

```
element.all(by.css('h4.ng-binding')).first(); //get the first element
element.all(by.css('h4.ng-binding')).get(0); //get the first element as get() function is a '0' based index
element.all(by.css('h4.ng-binding')).get(1); //get the second element
element.all(by.css('h4.ng-binding')).get(2); //get the third element
element.all(by.css('h4.ng-binding')).last(); //get the last element
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Now you can use functions like `.second(); .third(); .fourth();` etc. - I developed a small package - https://github.com/Marketionist/protractor-numerator - that can be used with protractor to select second, third, fourth, etc. elements.

Answer (score -3):

Use nth-child i.e.

```
element.all(by.css('h4.ng-binding:nth-child(2)'))...
```